# Query to return certain row always

Tags: php, mysql

Can you suggest a query where a condition will be executed always . Say :

```
if($country == 'hong-kong')
{
    $cond = "AND country = 'china'";
}

    $q = "
            SELECT 
                    *
            FROM
                tbl_people
            WHERE
                region = 'asia'
                $cond
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 0,15      
    ";
```

Now suppose `$country = 'hong-kong'` and it has total 4 members . What I want to know is is there any way so that if `$country = 'hong-kong'` I wll have 15 members in result set including the 4 members from `hong-kong` ?

Comment: I can't quite follow the question, but I expect a `UNION` will come into it, if you're looking to select all four entries for `country = 'hong-kong'` plus 11 *other* entries for `region = 'asia'` even if not in Hong Kong. Or you may be better off with two selects, since the number of results for the first (`country = 'hong-kong'`) will dictate how many results you want for the second.

Comment: could you please rephrase the question. It currently does not make any sense to me

Comment: I think you just need to use OR instead of AND.

Comment: @Lex: That won't ensure that all four `country = 'hong-kong'` entries are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want 15 random results from a larger set, but you want to be sure that all of the results matching `country = 'hong-kong'` are included in those 15.

I think you're going to want two queries, because the number of records returned by the first one (`country = 'hong-kong'`) will dictate the limit you put on the second query. E.g.:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_people
WHERE
    country = 'hong-kong'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,15
```

Then

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_people
WHERE
    region = 'asia' AND country <> 'hong-kong'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,X
```

...where `X` is `15 - N`, where `N` is how many rows were returned by your first query.

Then of course, you have to combine them in some kind of randomizing way (unless you want the Hong Kong results to be at the top/bottom/whatever of the list).

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder . Yes this is exactly what I want . Also,I am extracting the results in array_of_object ,so how can I add the array_of_objects ?

Comment: @FbtestEsdd: I don't know, what language are you using? All you've told us is that you're using MySQL, but you're clearly using some other language as well. PHP?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake . Thanks for pointing out . Yes I am using php

Comment: @FbtestEsdd: I'm not a PHP person, but a quick look at the docs suggests [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).